# Disable Mail.app message signing

Tags: macos, mac, apple-mail

Mail.app insists in digitally signing my outgoing messages, and I would like to disable this for my gmail account but have not managed to find out how.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

When you say "digitally signing", you mean that in the crypto sense, not just appending a typical "name and address" email signature to every email, right?

As an extreme measure, you could remove the public-key-certificate/private-key pair from your keychain. You could export the pair first so that you could easily re-import it if you ever wanted to sign a message or decrypt an encrypted message.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I mean in the crypto sense, not a text signature but rather a crypto hash of some sort that certifies that the message has been sent by me. Removing the key pair seems a bit drastic to me, but maybe I will have to end up doing that.

Comment: Note you will need to restart the Mail app or it will keep the keys cached and re-appearing in your Keychain.